# How to make horizontal scrollbar with columns with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, styles

I have this container that was made with boostrap:

[image]

The question is, how can i do to make a horizontal scrolling to maintan the aspect of the first picture of the container but in phone resolutions?..

This is the container in phone resolution:

[image]

I don't like it in that way..

This is my code:

```
<div class="card-body scroll" style="border: none;">
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="card" style="border: none;">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <h3 class="box-title w-text">Gestión de Empresas</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="box-tools">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Búsqueda" ng-model="searchField">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">
                                            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="input-group-text">
                                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                                        </span>
                                     </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <strong>Razón social</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <strong>RIF</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <strong>Dirección fiscal</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <strong>Activo</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <strong>Acciones</strong>
                        </div>
                        <hr style="border: none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h3>Ventor central</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h3>J-XYZ</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <h3>Empresa de pruebas</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <h3>Activo</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2" style="color: orange;">
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h3>Distribuidora regional del sol</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h3>J-1234567890</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <h3>Carretera nacional</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <h3>Activo</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2" style="color: orange;">
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue using the table that is provided with boostrap:

```
<table class="table">
                      <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <strong>Razón social</strong>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <strong>RIF</strong>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <strong>Dirección fiscal</strong>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <strong>Activo</strong>
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            <strong>Acciones</strong>
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td><h3>Ventor central</h3></td>
                          <td><h3>J-XYZ</h3></td>
                          <td><h3>Empresa de pruebas</h3></td>
                          <td><h3>Activo</h3></td>
                          <td><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down icon-fixed"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><h3>Distribuidora regional del sol</h3></td>
                          <td><h3>J-1234567890</h3></td>
                          <td><h3>Carretera nacional</h3></td>
                          <td><h3>Activo</h3></td>
                          <td><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down icon-fixed"></i></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

You can see the documentation here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/